# show errors in pycharm\intellij project view

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

In the java version of intellij, if there is an error the file in the project view is decorated with a red marker, so you can easily see that there is a problem:

[image: java error]

However, with pycharm\python plugin in intellij, the view is much different:

[image: python error]

Not only can you not see it in the project view on the file, you cannot see it on anything at all in the project view.

Is there a setting to change this? If not, is there a plugin to show errors in the project view?

I know that you can run code inspection manually, but, this is it's own view that you have to invoke, so that's not really a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Pycharm` shows errors in a project view, but Python is very different from Java - imports work more like C/C++ `#include`. You can check e.g. syntax errors, but unresolved dependencies are completely dependent on the runtime and this could depend on a lot of factors e.g. which file you ran as `__main__`.

Pasting something like that inside module marks it in `Project View` just like you showed in `Intellij`

[image: obvious error]

[image: Just like in intellij]

Much more complete and in-depth analysis (something similar to Java's PMD + Checkstyle) can be found in `Code -> Inspect Code...`

Comment: ok, this is interesting. You're right. Obvious syntax errors do show up in the project view. It's not actually a dependency problem, the problem is 'Class CustomHandler must implement all abstract methods'. Is there a way to make this error show up the same as the 'obvious error' ?

Comment: It is only a warning and I don't think you can fix that right now - pylint reports it as a warning too...

Comment: no, you can modify inspections, and make it an error. Which, I've done. However, it does not show up.

Comment: Yes you were right - I edited some warnings to errors, but it doesn't solve the problem, but **should** according to [their manual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Syntax+highlighting+and+error+indication): _If PyCharm, in course of code analysis, encounters any errors, they are immedeately reported in the following ways:[...] Moreover, the file in the Project tool window, and even the parent directory are also underlined._ I think it's a bug.

Comment: Yup, you're right... bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15345 thanks for confirming :)